# How do you query a table with a schema in Sequelize.js?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a table called 'wallets' in the 'dbo' schema of my postgresql database.
When I try to query it I get the error:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "wallets_id", "confirmed_balance", "unconfirmed_balance", "created_at", "updated_at" FROM "dbo.wallets" AS "dbo.wallets";
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "dbo.wallets" does not exist
```

This is my code:

```
get_dbo__wallets() : any {
    const options = this.getDatabaseDefaultOptions('dbo.wallets');
    const entity : types.IObjectWithStringKey = {};
    entity['wallets_id'] = {type: Sequelize.UUID, primaryKey: true, allowNull : false};
    entity['confirmed_balance'] = Sequelize.BIGINT;
    entity['unconfirmed_balance'] = Sequelize.BIGINT;
    return this._db.define('dbo.wallets', entity, options);
}

getDatabaseDefaultOptions(tableName : string) : types.IObjectWithStringKey {
    const options : types.IObjectWithStringKey = {};
    options['timestamps'] = true;
    options['createdAt'] = 'created_at';
    options['updatedAt'] = 'updated_at';
    options['underscored'] = false;

    options['paranoid'] = false;
    options['deletedAt'] = false;

    options['freezeTableName'] = true;
    options['tableName'] = tableName;
    return options;
}

//and then I call:  get_dbo__wallets().all()
```

**What should I change in the model definition to set the schema name correctly?**

Comment: you can add dbo to search_path for the user and ommit schema name

Comment: or `var initSequelize = new Sequelize( 'database', 'username', 'password', {dialect :'postgres', port:'5432',schema:dbo});`

Comment: Thanks. But I want to define it per table - because different tables are in different schemas. e.g. dbo.wallets, enum.sexes, banking.transactions.

Comment: then set search_path for user and omit schema name I guess

Comment: But what if I have banking.transactions and dbo.transactions? If I omit the schema it'll break. I need to specify schema on the table definition

Comment: then you have to build several `new Sequelize` object I believe

Comment: No, that won't work either, because queries need to pull data from multiple tables in different schemas. There must be a proper way of doing this in Sequelize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111416/discussion-between-richard-and-vao-tsun).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the schema to the table definition using the options object:

```
options['schema'] = 'dbo';
```

I found this by stepping into the query creation code at runtime - it doesn't appear to be in the documentation. I've opened a Sequelize bug to address this: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5864

Comment: Alternatively you could change the `search_path` for that database user.